# How to update post meta in Wordpress after importing posts from WP ALL IMPORT

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, wpallimport

I just finished importing the posts in multi language with WP ALL IMPORT. I'm using Qtranslate-X an QTS-Slug for slug translation. 
On the documentation page of WP ALL IMPORT I found out that they allow developers to write hooks. So I tried to hook into the 'pmxi_update_post_meta' with the following code but my posts still don't update the slug translation. (I'm testing with only 1 post first)

```
function my_update_post_meta() {
            update_post_meta( 9137, '_qts_slug_fr','adobe-corrige-des-failles-critiques-dans-reader-acrobat-flash-player-et-illustrator-1' );
            update_post_meta( 9137, '_qts_slug_en','adobe-patches-critical-flaws-in-reader-acrobat-flash-player-and-illustrator-1');  
        }

        add_action('pmxi_update_post_meta', 'my_update_post_meta', 10, 3);
```

Is there any who has experience on this ? I'd be appreciated for your help.

Comment: Is the action 'pmxi_update_post_meta' actually firing ?   It's not a standard wp action.  Also   If you are hard coding updates - ie one off changes, why not just use phpmyadmin to insert the records you need?

Comment: hi anmari, I wished I could. But the csv file that I received includes more than 3000 records and it's related to multi language translation so I cannot insert using SQL Query

Comment: Harley,  Is that hook actually firing? When is it supposed to fire? I suspect that it is designed to fire when  you do the import, and you say that you have finished importing, so most likely it is not firing at all.   Are trying to update data already imported?

Comment: True, I had a check, it wasn't firing at all. I switched to use their PRO edition and all of these are fixed. WP ALL IMPORT PRO provides updating custom meta fields without any code - everything is automatic.